# Synonymize [keyboard-shortcuts], [shortcut-key], [shortcuts], and [hotkeys]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I would like to propose synonymizing the following tags:

- [keyboard-shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) x 2929
- [shortcut-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut-key) x 46
- [shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcuts) x 360
- [hotkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hotkeys) x 706

These tags all refer to the same thing. (Note that [shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut), [desktop-shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/desktop-shortcut), [windows-shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-shortcut), [autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey), [registerhotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registerhotkey) and [global-hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global-hotkey) refer to different things.)

Since [keyboard-shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) is the most used and the most descriptive too, I think that should become the master of the others.

Comment: Concurr aside from [tag:shortcut], which contains many questions not having anything to do with keyboard-shortcuts.

Comment: @Ded That's why I said that [shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) refers to something different, as explained in [its wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/shortcut/info).

Comment: ehm, meant [tag:shortcuts] (the plural). And even if we remove all but the keyboard-shortcuts from it, it should be merged not synonymized.

Comment: I have to wonder in what way this is related to software development as a topic.

Comment: @Braiam Like implementing a software to catch keyboard shortcuts, combos and how to differentiate between plain key strokes and shortcuts.

Comment: @TheMaster which depends on the interfaces I'm targeting and therefore unlikely that there will be someone that is an expert about all of them. If I want shortcuts on Linux the same as Windows I have to read the .desktop specification, which means nothing to Windows. Keyboard shortcuts for Qt are different than glib and different from X and wayland and Windows. What I'm doing is rarely a good tag if "what I'm using" change the answers dramatically.