# Perhaps the [shortcut] tag is not actually getting us there quicker?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I was writing a questions about keyboard shortcuts when I stumbled across the [shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) tag. It's currently [described as](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shortcut/info):

> A route more direct than the one ordinarily taken.
> A method or means of doing something more directly and quickly than and often not so thoroughly as by ordinary procedure.

#### Tag overview

It currently has about [2,600 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) associated with it, which are mostly about:

1. Keyboard shortcuts
2. Shortcuts files (e.g. "Create desktop shortcut" on Windows)
3. Shortcuts in the most general sense - ways of doing things that are faster (but perhaps less thorough?)

#### Redundant and vague definitions

Those are very broad uses of the same tag. I think that **1** is an inappropriate use of the tag, since [keyboard-shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) is its own tag, which has not been synonymised despite [proposals to that effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277621/synonymize-keyboard-shortcuts-shortcut-key-shortcuts-hotkeys).

**2** Also has its own tag - [shortcut-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut-file). So presumably the use of a more generic [shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) tag only muddies the waters? The tag description for 'shortcut' also references this definition.

**3** is very broad. Is it helpful to have a tag that's just about shortcuts in general? If so, what qualifies as a shortcut? When might somebody be looking for help in relation to shortcuts in this sense?

#### Possible actions

I think that one of two things needs to happen:

1. Make the shortcut tag clearer and more specific, to avoid confusion with [keyboard-shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) and [shortcut-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut-file). Determine what qualifies as a shortcut and what does not.
2. Burninate the tag. It's too vague to be useful, and it makes the site harder to use because it results in the mis-tagging of [keyboard-shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) and [shortcut-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut-file) questions.

Comment: If you want the tag to be burninated, read and follow [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate)